# Google App Engine (datastore) - will a deleted key regenerate?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I've got a simple question about `datastore keys`. If I delete an entity, is there any possibility that the key will be created again? or each key is unique and can be generated only one-time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible to re-use keys.

Easy to test, for example using the datastore admin page:

- create an entity for one of your entity models using a custom/specified key name and some property values
- delete the entity
- create another one using the **same** key name and different property values...

As for the keys with auto-generated IDs it is theoretically possible, but I guess rather unlikely due to the high number of possibilities. From [Assigning identifiers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/entities#Go_Assigning_identifiers):

> Cloud Datastore can be configured to generate auto IDs using [two
>   different auto id policies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appref#auto_policy_id):
>
> - The default policy generates a random sequence of unused IDs that are approximately uniformly distributed. Each ID can be up to 16
>     decimal digits long.
> - The legacy policy creates a sequence of non-consecutive smaller integer IDs.

Comment: One weird thing about IDs is that mine all start with 4, 5, or 6 so they seem to be uniformly distributed over some subset of 16 digit numbers.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill that *might* be intentional - for example the leading digit(s) could encode some info (region/zone routing/namespace/class of service/etc). I wouldn't worry too much about it ;)